# Resize a div on border drag and drop without adding extra markup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an absolute positioned side panel and I need to change its width by dragging this border. Also I need to change cursor on border hover. Is it possible to do this without adding another div for dragging?

Here is the markup:

```css
#right_panel {
    position: absolute;
    border-left: solid 3px #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="right_panel"></div>
</body>
```

I don't need a full solution. A Yes (with documentation reference)/No answer is enough. I don't need an answer with a helper `div`. I already have one:

```js
var m_pos;
function resize(e){
    var parent = resize_el.parentNode;
    var dx = m_pos - e.x;
    m_pos = e.x;
    parent.style.width = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(parent, '').width) + dx) + "px";
}

var resize_el = document.getElementById("resize");
resize_el.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    m_pos = e.x;
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
}, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
}, false);
```

```css
#right_panel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 96px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#resize {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: w-resize;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="right_panel">
        <div id="resize"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Again, this is the functionality I want, except I want to remove the extra `div`.

Comment: I assume you mean 'dragging'. Do you have ANY Javascript for this or are you asking us to write it for you?

Comment: atleast show some code which you have already tried and not worked

Comment: I'm asking is it possible or not and some recomendations. I don't need to solve this problem because I already have a solution with another div for dragging and resizing parent div. I only want to make the markup cleaner. Here is the solution with another div: http://jsfiddle.net/kxr96dzg/1/
And sorry. English isn't my native language.

Comment: I provided my code. Can you help now?

Comment: @Anton In case you missed it, I added an answer that might work for you (a bit late but I hope it helps!) -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53220241/428486

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do this without an extra div. Use css and `::after` to create the border and change the cursor. Use [`MouseEvent.offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) to determine whether to process a click in the element.

In your example, you want a click on the main div, but only on the first 4 pixels. You can do that by checking for `e.offsetX < 4` in your click handler:

```js
const BORDER_SIZE = 4;
const panel = document.getElementById("right_panel");

let m_pos;
function resize(e){
  const dx = m_pos - e.x;
  m_pos = e.x;
  panel.style.width = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(panel, '').width) + dx) + "px";
}

panel.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
  if (e.offsetX < BORDER_SIZE) {
    m_pos = e.x;
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
}, false);
```

```css
#right_panel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 96px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0ff;
}

#right_panel::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="right_panel"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: How to limit the `resize()` to a certain % of the viewport?

Comment: This worked fine on Firefox for me, but on Chrome when the right panel became extremely narrow, it started going crazy - the panel would shrink faster than I moved the mouse over. It's because I was using flexbox and Chrome wasn't respecting `flex-shrink: 0` all the time. To fix that, I changed the line that contains `getComputedStyle` to be:  `panel.style.width = (parseInt(panel.style.width) + dx) + 'px';`.

Comment: One more thing, `panel.style.width` might not be a number (could be `''` for example), so you should check for that and fallback to `getComputedStyle` as above.  The first time the `resize` function is called, it will fall back to `getComputedStyle`, but all other times, it'll use `panel.style.width`.

Answer (score 30):

i hope it may help you

http://jsfiddle.net/T4St6/82/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left_panel"> left content! </div>
    <div id="right_panel">
        <div id="drag"></div> right content!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
 #left_panel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100px;
    background: grey;
}

#right_panel {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    color:#fff;
    background: black;
}
 #drag {
    position: absolute;
    left: -4px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 8px;
    cursor: w-resize;
}
```

JQUERY

```
var isResizing = false,
    lastDownX = 0;

$(function () {
    var container = $('#container'),
        left = $('#left_panel'),
        right = $('#right_panel'),
        handle = $('#drag');

    handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
        lastDownX = e.clientX;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
        if (!isResizing) 
            return;

        var offsetRight = container.width() - (e.clientX - container.offset().left);

        left.css('right', offsetRight);
        right.css('width', offsetRight);
    }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
        // stop resizing
        isResizing = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a working solution but I'm trying to do this without a helper div for dragging.

Comment: Add "return false" to the end of mousemove callback to prevent text selection in the divs.

Comment: is this also doable in bootstrap?

Comment: @PirateApp can you please explain, what you want to achieve? do you want to use bootstrap.css?

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa yes can this layout be achieved with bootstrap columns

Comment: @PirateApp yes it is possible, you need to find the proper css class of bootstrap, also mixture of classes.

Answer (score 19):

Without jQuery:

```js
var isResizing = false;

(function() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container"),
    left = document.getElementById("left_panel"),
    right = document.getElementById("right_panel"),
    handle = document.getElementById("drag");

  handle.onmousedown = function(e) {
    isResizing = true;
  };

  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
    if (!isResizing) {
      return;
    }

    var offsetRight = container.clientWidth - (e.clientX - container.offsetLeft);

    left.style.right = offsetRight + "px";
    right.style.width = offsetRight + "px";
  }

  document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    // stop resizing
    isResizing = false;
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left_panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100px;
  background: grey;
}

#right_panel {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  background: black;
}

#drag {
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 8px;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left_panel"> left content! </div>
    <div id="right_panel">
      <div id="drag"></div> right content!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8):

**2022 Answer:**  
This now can be done , by simple using "resize" property in **css** only, 
make sure to make overflow auto for that div, so resize can work .

as in this snippet:

```
#right_panel {
    position: absolute;
    border-left: solid 3px #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
```