# How to make DIVs resizable from not all sides

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some kind layout made using bootstrap.

```
 <div class = row style="width:400px; height:400px">
        <div class = "col-sm-12" style="height:50%; border:2px solid;"></div>
        <div class = "col-sm-6" style="height:50%; border:2px solid;"></div>
        <div class = "col-sm-6" style="height:50%; border:2px solid;" ></div>
 </div>
```

Visually it looks:

[image]

Maybe someone can suggest any framework, or code solution to make DIVs re sizable, but only in some directions, not allow to re size sides which are outer. Here is explanation in picture:

[image]

Maybe someone can sugest code or lib how to make that.
I use angular, bootstrap.

Comment: Question is how to make some sides re sizable, 
I use also angular so I prefer angular libs.

Comment: so basically, you are admitting that the question is off topic? http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic #4, "4.Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I've met the problem, that I have no Idea how to achieve that. If you can help me understand what is needed for such functionality: some libs, or enough plain JS code. I listening you.

Comment: You have **no** angular code here at all.  **none**. You also have no code showing what you have tried to do;  Instead, you have request for someone to make a suggestion on where you can find some code.  This is not on topic for the site, and definitely doesn't apply to the angularjs tag.

Comment: that is why, I as help, I need Idea for code...

Comment: @Edgar : Could you please demo on JSfiiddle for whatever you have tried. So that we can go ahead of that and lookout something.

Answer (score 1):

From the picture I understand you want to drag and resize div from border lines.

css3 has a resize property with syntax:

```
resize: none|both|horizontal|vertical|initial|inherit;
```

with following css:

```
div {
   resize: both;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

You get nicely resizable box from both vertical and horizontal.

**More:**

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

*Note: This feature, though, is not supported by IE.*

Comment: but I think he wants the re-sizable arrows on the border whichever is resizable. Exactly as he shown in the image with **Red Arrows**

Comment: Arrows illustrate desired actions of resize to happen, when resizable is activated.

Comment: Yeah... but here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp its not like that. At this link at right bottom corner we have small diagonal lines that are used to resize the border. I am unable to re-size by dragging only the bottom or the right border.

Comment: Someone has tried what @SandeepKushwah says http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233180/resize-div-on-border-drag-and-drop but at least there the resulting code to achieve that is not very good looking.