# Resize and rearrange divs through drag & drop and dynamic CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs that I want my users to be able to hit a button and arrange these two divs top/down or left/right.  I have implemented it but whenever I arrange them left/right, the right div often overflows to the bottom of the left div.

I have seen [another similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233180/resize-div-on-border-drag-and-drop/26233793#26233793) that talks about resizing left/right divs, but I still don't know what exactly caused my right div to overflow.  Any help is appreciated!

Here is my example:

```js
var d = $('#divider'); // divider between top and bottom divs
var t = $('#tl'); // top/left div
var b = $('#br'); // bottom/right div
var h = $('body').height();
var w = $('body').width();
var isDragging = false;
var isLandscape = false;

d.mousedown(function(e) {
  isDragging = true;
});
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  isDragging = false;
}).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (isDragging) {
    if (!isLandscape) {
      t.css('height', e.pageY);
      b.css('height', h - e.pageY - d.height());
      d.css('height', h - t.height() - b.height());
    } else {
      t.css('width', e.pageX);
      b.css('width', w - e.pageX - d.width());
      d.css('width', w - t.width() - b.width());
    }
  }
});

var rotateBtn = document.getElementById('rotateScreen');
if (rotateBtn) {
  rotateBtn.addEventListener('click', rotateDisplay, false);
} else {
  throw error;
}

function rotateDisplay() {
  if (!isLandscape) {
    isLandscape = true;
    t.css('height', h);
    t.css('width', Math.round(0.75 * w));
    b.css('height', h);
    b.css('width', Math.round(0.24 * w));
    d.css('height', h);
    d.css('width', w - t.width() - b.width());
    d.css('cursor', 'w-resize');
  } else {
    isLandscape = false;
    t.css('height', Math.round(0.75 * h));
    t.css('width', w);
    t.css('float', 'left');
    b.css('height', Math.round(0.24 * h));
    b.css('width', w);
    b.css('float', 'left');
    d.css('height', h - t.height() - b.height());
    d.css('width', w);
    d.css('cursor', 'n-resize');
    d.css('float', 'left');
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#br {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24%;
  float: left;
  background: gold;
}

#tl {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  float: left;
  background: navy;
}

#divider {
  height: 1%;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}

#control {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="control">
  <button id="rotateScreen">&#128257;</button>
</div>
<div id="tl">This is the top/left div</div>
<div id="divider"></div>
<div id="br">This is the bottom/right div</div>
```

Comment: There is no allowable value of "bottom" for the `float` CSS property?

Comment: @KenH. you're right, I was not very familiar with CSS so I was just playing with it.  But even if I get rid of those, I still have the overflowing issue.

Comment: does this "overflow" depend on the screen width?  I guess that I'm a little confused by what you mean by overflow, but if I change the width of the screen then I see that the div will move down below the "top" div as necessary?

Comment: The initial arrangement is top/down.  If you click the button on the top left corner, the two divs are supposed to be arranged side-by-side.  But the right div for some reason could not be displayed right next to the left div and "overflowed" to the bottom.

Comment: As I see it, it is screen-width dependent?  If the screen is wide enough to display both divs side-by-side then it will, otherwise  it will float the right div down beneath the top div.  The main thing that you are doing with the click is to change the widths of the divs.  Would you be able to change to using flexbox as the display mode, then you can change the orientation of the divs with the flex properties like `flex-direction`?  That might be a solution?  I'm not sure if that fits with your overall goal for this?

Comment: I don't think it's screen-width dependent.  If you put it to left/right mode and drag the border around, you will see that sometimes the right div does come to the right place.  I will look into flexbox though. Thanks @KenH!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151170/discussion-between-crwang-and-ken-h).