# CSS resize horizontal?

Tags: html, css, resize

I want to have a box (div or textarea or another element) that the user can click the right border of and drag the right side border to make the box smaller or larger.

I have been able to create a div that with the css "resize: horizontal;" attribute,  but I can't find a way to style the grabber so it is aligned on the right border of the element.

This is the closest I have been able to get.
I would prefer to not have to use javascript and
I definitely don't want to include an external package or library just to achieve this.

```css
textarea {
  resize: horizontal; 
}  
::-webkit-resizer {
   border-left: 1px solid black;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<textarea>some text here.</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the whole border, by default `resize` will insert a resizable icon at the bottom right corner only, and only this little icon will be draggable.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

To have the whole "border', you could use this solution:
[Resize a div on border drag and drop without adding extra markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233180/resize-a-div-on-border-drag-and-drop-without-adding-extra-markup)