# Resizing a canvas element via dragging the edges

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, resize, fabricjs

I'm trying to make it so users of my site can resize their canvas by simply dragging the sides of it. I'm using [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) which allows me to resize elements from within the canvas but I need to resize the actual canvas itself. I'm fine with using any new libraries you recommend.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIaAw.png) should help you understand a bit more of what I want.

As a side note, the Fabric.js team have an interactive toolbox [here](http://fabricjs.com/customization) for you to experiment if you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put your fabric.js canvas in a wrapper div.
2. Make the wrapper resizable. Here I'm using CSS [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize). It only adds a bottom-left corner as a resize control but it's good enough for the sake of the demo. To have all the edges as controls you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53220241/5045563).
3. Detect the wrapper's size change. Ideally, you would use something like [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver). However, since browser support is still about 80% at the time of posting this, you might feel the need to use a polyfill or write something specific to your case. A simple `setInterval` with size check might prove to be sufficient.
4. When the wrapper's size changes, set new fabric.js canvas dimensions via `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  left: 100,
  top: 50,
}))

const canvasWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
// initial dimensions
canvasWrapper.style.width = '300px'
canvasWrapper.style.height = '150px'

let width
let height
setInterval(() => {
  const newWidth = canvasWrapper.clientWidth
  const newHeight = canvasWrapper.clientHeight
  if (newWidth !== width || newHeight !== height) {
    width = newWidth
    height = newHeight
    canvas.setWidth(newWidth)
    canvas.setHeight(newHeight)
  }
}, 100)
```

```css
#wrapper {
    border: solid 1px black;
    resize: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that's going to be easy, but it's definitely possible. First, you may wonder about the native browser element `resize` CSS property and `ResizeObserver`, however those have poor support right now. Your best option is to:

1. Create a canvas element
2. Detect mousemoves on the canvas:

   - If the mousemove happens around the edge of the canvas, set the cursor to be the resize icon in the proper direction
   - If the mouse is currently down, resize the canvas based on the mouse's position.

Remember that every time you resize a canvas, the current image on the canvas is wiped.

Comment: Do you know of any way to make the canvas not get wiped by any chance?

Comment: You can just use `getImageData` and `putImageData` to preserve the raw canvas image, but you probably just want to tell Fabric.js to re-render the canvas for you -- perhaps through `canvas.renderAll()` http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#renderAll

Comment: Resizing `canvas` by it's attributes `width` and `height` (NOT css style), will always wipe it. You'll need to repaint it yourself or by some fabricjs function (I don't know how fabricjs works).